# I can't install PhoneGap plugin for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, eclipse-plugin, phonegap-plugins

I tried to install PhoneGap plugin for Eclipse. So I went to Eclipse -> Help -> Install new software -> Add
And I copied this link:

http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2.9/download/

Eclipse tried to install it and in the middle of the installation progress this window appeared:

[The Image](http://uped.rupai.net/pic/d383ec94720d.jpg)

What should I do? I wanna have PhoneGap in Eclipse.

Comment: I can't see the image, site seems to have an error.

Comment: you were right. I updated it.

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap is now powered by an Apache project called Cordova. You can read more about that [here](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/).

Check out their step-by-step "[Getting Started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides)" guides for developing mobile apps using Cordova.

Answer (score 2):

You might be installing it in your office or so where most of the sites are blocked. But you can install it by replacing `http` with `https` and then try.

https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2.9/download/

This will work.

Comment: More likely that https is blocked than http :P

Comment: @TehHippo In my office almost all http is blocked except all https :P

Comment: what version of eclipse you using?

Comment: This is my version: / Version: Juno Release / 
Build id: 20120614-1722

Comment: I meant the details… Not the dialog

Comment: I updated the Image. And it's now with details. Please see it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as an administrator? You'll need admin privileges for this. See more in this post: http://ethellenterprises.com/2011/05/phonegap-blackberry-and-windows-7-access-denied/

Comment: You shouldn't need admin privillages to install it in Eclipse though.

Comment: I'm in my own account that it's administrator. So probably the problem is for something else.